# How to Change the Source of an Image W/JS

Tags: javascript, html, mouseenter, mouseout

I have to change the src of an image using java script and I am pretty sure i hit a road block, in the html I have 3 li elements and in the id is the source of the mouseenter img. I feel like I am close but so far. Heres my code so far. Thanks for any help!

Javascript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);};

window.onload = function () {
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img"), 
    imgNode, 
    i, 
    URLone, 
    URLtwo, 
    link, 
    image;
for (i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
    imgNode = imgElements[i];
}
imgNode.mouseenter = function () {
    var img = this;
    URLtwo = img.getAttribute('id');
    img.src = URLtwo;
}
imgNode.mouseout = function () {
    var img = this;
    URLone = img.getAttribute('src');
    img.src = URLone;
};
 //preload
for (i = 0; i < links.length * 2; i++) {
    link = links[i];
    image = new Image();
    image.src = link.src;
    image = new Image();
    image.src = link.id;
}};
```

HTML ::

```
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
    <ul id="image_rollovers">
        <li><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="images/h4.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="" id="images/h5.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="" id="images/h6.jpg"></li>
    </ul>        
</section>
```

Working jQuery :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#image_rollovers img").each(function() {
 var oldURL = $(this).attr("src"); // gets the src attribute
 var newURL = $(this).attr("id"); // gets the id attribute
 // preload images
 var rolloverImage = new Image();
 rolloverImage.src = newURL;
 $(this).hover(
 function() {
 $(this).attr("src", newURL); // sets the src attribute
 },
 function() {
 $(this).attr("src", oldURL); // sets the src attribute
 }
 ); // end hover
 }); // end each
}); // end ready
```

Comment: Describe your road block. What is the problem?

Comment: I think it may be something to do with the nodes or logic that i am trying to understand and use. its new to me this week and after reading i still dont fully understand it

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery?  Also, is this homework? If so the rules on SO are a little different; mark it with the homework tag.

Comment: It is though it will not allow me to as i just signed up and don't have 1500 points otherwise i would. I am not allowed to use jQuery for this assignment as it is in the book already.

Comment: What is not working? Is the original image not showing? Not showing `onmouseover`? Not showing `onmouseout`?

Comment: You can set the `src` attribute of an element with javascript's setAttribute() function.

Comment: The mouseenter is not working when hovering over the image

Comment: so I think i need to figure out how to make sure I am working with the correct element when working with nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
   (function(imgNode) {
      imgNode.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
         var img = this;
         URLtwo = img.getAttribute('id');
         img.src = URLtwo;
      }, false);

      imgNode.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
         var img = this;
         URLone = img.getAttribute('src');
         img.src = URLone;
      }, false);
   })(imgElements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems in your code.

- First for loop closing right away, instead should close after your
  imgNode.mouseout function

```js
for (i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
    imgNode = imgElements[i];

imgNode.mouseenter = function () {
    var img = this;
    URLtwo = img.getAttribute('id');
    img.src = URLtwo;
}
imgNode.mouseout = function () {
    var img = this;
    URLone = img.getAttribute('src');
    img.src = URLone;
};
}
 //preload
for (i = 0; i < links.length * 2; i++) {
    link = links[i];
    image = new Image();
    image.src = link.src;
    image = new Image();
    image.src = link.id;
}};
```

- Last for loop runs 6 times but there are only 3  tags in html. When it coming to loop no. 3 it doesn't get any value for link.src.
- Also links variable provides a collection of 'li' tags and not 'img', last for loop requires src from link.src which doesn't have any value, need to change

  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("li"),
  to

  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),

Try that. Hopefully after correcting above errors your code should work.

Comment: why would the for loop need to close after the mouse out function thank you for catching the loop at the bottom and the links var

Comment: I am not sure if you want to attach the mouseenter and mouseout events only to the last element in imgElements array. In your code the loop runs completely the value in imgNode will be the last one and the events will be attached to the last element only. I am unsure about your purpose of running the for loop and attaching events otherwise.